# Why is $GLOBALS['content_width'] needed if site is responsive?

Tags: theme-development

Help to understand its practical usefulness today.
I had written it in my theme, but practically it does not use — all embedded content are responsive and don't use value of this variable.
Maybe `'content_width'` is outdated?

Answer (score 0):

Embedded content is not responsive "by magic" someone needs to write code to actually make it so, and some default needs to be there in any case, and actually not all site are responsive, and some even can not be responsive.

You might want to establish a base line, for example the size of the image being displayed when the page is loaded before responsiveness kick in, to make it a better experience for the majority of your users (95% of them are on desktop? maybe good idea to start with a desktop mode).

OTOH, regardless of responsiveness, the `$content_width` is a global and therefor it is better to avoid using it and pretend it does not exist as much as you can.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it necessary for unexpected embeddeds? This limitation of unexpected behavior embeddeds?

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand where does "unexpected" come from

Comment: So, is `content_width` needed just in case? "unexpected": I mean as the result of users actions.

Comment: Well, IIRC it has a default set by core. If your site/theme works without modifying it than you may as well forget about it. I know that I always do.

Comment: If I have to write this setting in my theme, but I do not use it, what value should I specify in it?

Comment: The width you use for the content in a simple post page. That is the origin of the concept so at least you will be compatible to it

Comment: `The width you use for the content in a simple post page.`  
But if my theme have different temlates with diferent width of content?

Comment: I think you are overthinking it. If your theme is responsive just use what you think is going to be the most used format